# DevExpress - Como deshabilitar la edición de una celda si otra celda tiene valor

Tags: angularjs, datagrid, devexpress

Mi problema es el siguiente: Tengo un dataGrid de DevExpress donde hay varias filas, entre ellas hay una que se llama Variedad y otra VariedadSupuesta. Mi problema es que no consigo bloquear la edición e incluso el acceso (el tabular no pase por dentro de la celda) de esta celda llamada VariedadSupuesta cuando hay un valor dentro de Variedad.

He conseguido llegar al punto donde tengo que realizar el cambio de la propiedad de edición de la celda e incluso obtengo el objeto de la celda a cambiar (código más abajo) pero no encuentro la forma de bloquear esa celda.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

**Código JS:**

```
onRowPrepared: function (e) { 
                var dataGrid = e.component;  
                var rowIndex = dataGrid.getRowIndexByKey(e.key);  
                if (e.data !== undefined) {                      
                    if(e.data.Id_Variedad != undefined && e.data.Id_Variedad !=null)
                    {                              
                        var this5 = dataGrid.getCellElement(rowIndex, 'VariedadSupuesta');                       
                    }
                }
            },
```

**Vista del GRID:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr el comportamiento requerido, maneje el  evento [onEditorPreparing](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onEditorPreparing) para deshabilitar un editor en función de su condición:

```
onEditorPreparing: function(e) {  
  if (e.parentType !== "dataRow" || e.dataField !== tu campo aquí) {  
    return;  
  }  
  e.editorOptions.disabled = su condicion aquí;  
},
```

Para forzar este evento cuando se cambia el valor del editor en otra columna, anule la  función [setCellValue](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#setCellValue) de esa columna:

```
setCellValue: function(rowData, value) {  
  this.defaultSetCellValue(rowData, value);  
}
```

Vea el  [ejemplo de CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bormOP?editors=0010) que ilustra esto.

---

Adicional a esto puede encontrar mas ejemplos de utilidad aquí:

> - [Cómo deshabilitar la edición de una celda después de cambiar el valor de otro editor en modo de edición por lotes](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T486867/dxdatagrid-how-to-disable-editing-of-a-cell-after-changing-another-editor-s-value-in)
> - [Cómo deshabilitar una celda de cuadrícula basada en un valor de otro editor](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T397321/dxdatagrid-how-to-disable-a-grid-cell-based-on-a-value-of-another-editor)
> - [Cómo deshabilitar la edición de una celda después de cambiar otra celda del valor del editor de búsqueda](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T638658/how-to-disable-editing-of-a-cell-after-changing-another-cell-of-lookup-editor-s-value)